# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Tor's second election has come to a close. We are delighted to appoint your new moderators:

[image: Alexey Vesnin]  [image: Swangie]
They'll be joining the [existing crew](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). Please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

You can view the election history [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/election/2).

Answer (score 3):

Thank you so much for appointing me as a moderator. I am proud to help improve the Tor Stack Exchange community. I also look forward to working closely with the other moderators, Jens Kubieziel and Alexey Vesnin.